# Why can't I access my USB Device connected to a D-LINK 850L router?

Tags: networking, macos, router, samba, dlna

I own a D-Link 850L router. It has a USB port. I have connected my external drive to it and enabled DLNA and SAMBA from the router configuration page.

I am using macOS. I can see the drive name in locations/rlx-linux/DIR-850L. But when I click it, I get an error message:

> “The operation can’t be completed because the original item for “DIR-850L” can’t be found.”

On my routers configuration page there are just options for enabling/ disabling SAMBA and DLNA.

Why can’t I access my USB Device connected to a D-Link 850L router?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://eu.dlink.com/uk/en/support/faq/routers/mydlink-routers/dir-880l/how-do-i-access-the-usb-media-that-is-connected-to-my-router